# Using patindex in SQL Server to check six continuous numeric values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to check if a string has 6 continuous numeric values in a string with the `PATINDEX` function.

Examples (in parenthesis appears the number if it fits 6 digits):

```
case 1 - s24334fth06 
case 2 - 234567tgf       (234567)
case 3 - t443786ftu03    (443786)
case 4 - tt43456
```

Expected results:

```
case 1 - 0   (it has only 5 continuous numeric values, so no index is given)
case 2 - 1   
case 3 - 2  
case 4 - 0
```

I have tried with

```
PATINDEX('%[0-9]{6}%', @string)
```

it gives 0 for all cases.

Comment: The answers below will work for you, but REGEX isn't fully supported in SQL Server hence your {6} won't work.

Answer (score 3):

You may actually just use the `LIKE` operator here:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE col LIKE '%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%';
```

SQL Server has little built in regex support, but they tried to compensate for it partially by enhancing `LIKE` with some regex capabilities.

Comment: . . I think Sybase made that original design choice.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Good to know this :-)

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', @string)
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3667274315a470228e29d49d02898988)**

---

And extraction(first occurrence):

```
SELECT c, 
  SUBSTRING(c,NULLIF(PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', c),0), 6) AS r
FROM tab;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=64ae589d41f46292a27051fd80078d2b)**

```
┌──────────────┬────────┐
│      c       │   r    │
├──────────────┼────────┤
│ s24334fth06  │ null   │
│ 234567tgf    │ 234567 │
│ t443786ftu03 │ 443786 │
│ tt43456      │ null   │
└──────────────┴────────┘
```

Answer (score 2):

Why would you use `patindex()` instead of `like` and `case`?

```
select t.*,
       (case when col like '%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%' then 1 else 0 end) as six_flag
from t;
```